# Want to show "loading" image during the page loading - Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am using the following code for displaying the products of an e-commerce website. While the products are being loaded, the images will slowly fade out and then will come again normal. I want to show an loading image (like [this](https://si0.twimg.com/a/1311111325/phoenix/img/loader.gif)) when the new products are being loaded. What code should I include in the below code to get this done?

```
function displayProducts(){     

        $('#product_show').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete
            setProducts();
            $('#product_show').fadeIn('slow');
      });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're #product_show element is, but assuming it is some sort of container, you can just append that image to it (maybe absolutely positioned in the middle). and when it compeletes, remove the image.

Something Like:

```
$('#product_show').append('<img src="..." class="progress"/>').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete
            setProducts();
            $('#product_show').remove('img.progress').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I find it's best to have a loading gif div always present, and just hide/make transparent once load is complete.

1. Fade out existing, loading gif becomes visible.
2. Waiting on callback from loading of the new product (ajax call or what are you doing there?)
3. When you get the callback, then you fade in the new product. Loading gif hidden.

Nice loading gif generator: http://www.ajaxload.info/